# Angular 5 Call Function and exit after a certain time

Tags: angular, timeout, delay

I'm blocked how to implement this specification :

I call a method update() :

```
this.contratService.update(lineSelected.id).subscribe(response => {
   if (response.status === 201) {
       ....
   }
}, error => {
   console.log('Error in contrat update');
});
```

I want to wait 30 seconds after update called before to show another error.

How can I implement this feature?

Note: I understand that setTimeout, execute an instruction after a certain time and note wait a certain time after a method was called

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timeout()` pipeable operator of `rxjs`;

```
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
...


this.contratService.update(lineSelected.id)
  .pipe(
     timeout(30000)
   )
  .subscribe(response => {
     if (response.status === 201) {
         ....
     }
  }, error => {
   console.log('Error in contrat update');
});
```

Ref: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout